# rust actix: How to process asynchronously requests within single connection?

Tags: rust, actix-web

I want to implement such a behavior that within single http connection server
receives multiple requests, processes them and responses are passed back in order of completion.

Here is code for actix:

```rust
#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
struct NumberToProcess {
    x: f64,
    job_id: u64,
}

#[derive(Serialize, Debug)]
struct ProcessResult {
    x: f64,
    job_id: u64,
    started: String,
    elapsed_ms: u64,
}

#[post("/sqrt")]
async fn my_sqrt(req: web::Json<NumberToProcess>) -> impl Responder {

    let date = Local::now();
    let started = time::Instant::now();
    trace!("New task: {:?}", req);

    let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();

    /* some heavy computations */
    let f = req.x;
    thread::sleep(time::Duration::from_millis(rng.gen_range(2000u64, 4000u64)));
    let r = f.sqrt();
    /* heavy computations end */

    let res = ProcessResult {
        x: r,
        job_id: req.job_id,
        started: date.format("%Y.%m.%d %H:%M:%S").to_string(),
        elapsed_ms: started.elapsed().as_millis() as u64,
    };

    HttpResponse::Ok().json(res)
}
```

I test it with `netcat`:

```sh
nc 127.0.0.1 8080 <<EOF
POST /sqrt HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Accept: */*
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 26

{"x":1.5, "job_id": 1000}
POST /sqrt HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Accept: */*
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 26

{"x":2.5, "job_id": 1001}
POST /sqrt HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Accept: */*
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 26

{"x":3.5, "job_id": 1002}
POST /sqrt HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Accept: */*
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 26

{"x":4.5, "job_id": 1003}
EOF
```

The problem is that requests are processed in order, synchronously.

The result is:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
content-length: 87
content-type: application/json
date: Mon, 31 May 2021 13:55:49 GMT

{"x":1.224744871391589,"job_id":1000,"started":"2021.05.31 16:55:49","elapsed_ms":3475}HTTP/1.1 200 OK
content-length: 88
content-type: application/json
date: Mon, 31 May 2021 13:55:49 GMT

{"x":1.5811388300841898,"job_id":1001,"started":"2021.05.31 16:55:52","elapsed_ms":3500}HTTP/1.1 200 OK
content-length: 88
content-type: application/json
date: Mon, 31 May 2021 13:55:49 GMT

{"x":1.8708286933869707,"job_id":1002,"started":"2021.05.31 16:55:56","elapsed_ms":2040}HTTP/1.1 200 OK
content-length: 88
content-type: application/json
date: Mon, 31 May 2021 13:55:49 GMT

{"x":2.1213203435596424,"job_id":1003,"started":"2021.05.31 16:55:58","elapsed_ms":2201}
```

Is it possible to make actix (or some other web framework) to proccess requests without waiting for
completion of previous request within same connection?

Answer (score 1):

An issue with your implementation is that `std::thread::sleep` will *block* execution of the async context; instead you should use `tokio@0.2`'s `tokio::time::delay_for(...).await` to *yield* execution. If you've actually intended to use `std::thread::sleep` to *simulate* a blocking computation, then you should use something like `tokio::spawn_blocking` so that you don't block processing of other requests.

> ... and responses are passed back in order of completion.

What you have done with `netcat` is an example of *HTTP pipelining*. Even if the requests are processed concurrently, you'll always get responses back in the order that you requested them.

If you want to them to come back in the order of completion, you'll either have to make separate requests or use a client that provides *HTTP/2 multiplexing*. This can be done with an up-to-date `curl` command:

```
$ curl -Z \
-d '{"x":1.5,"job_id":1000}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -X POST http://localhost:8080/sqrt --next \
-d '{"x":2.5,"job_id":1001}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -X POST http://localhost:8080/sqrt --next \
-d '{"x":3.5,"job_id":1002}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -X POST http://localhost:8080/sqrt --next \
-d '{"x":4.5,"job_id":1003}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -X POST http://localhost:8080/sqrt
```

```
{"x":1.224744871391589,"job_id":1000,"started":"2021.05.31 16:32:41","elapsed_ms":2406}
{"x":1.8708286933869707,"job_id":1002,"started":"2021.05.31 16:32:44","elapsed_ms":2631}
{"x":2.1213203435596424,"job_id":1003,"started":"2021.05.31 16:32:44","elapsed_ms":2717}
{"x":1.5811388300841898,"job_id":1001,"started":"2021.05.31 16:32:44","elapsed_ms":3065}
```

The connection is upgraded as part of the first request, so the first one is synchronous while the following requests are all made in parallel.

Comment: Thank you for clarification about pipelining and multiplexing, good point. `sleep` is actually used to _simulate_ expensive computations. Will take a look at `tokio::spawn_blocking`.

Comment: Well, `spawn_blocking` works with _multiplexing_. But in my case the requesting side (not a browser, it is another service) is using plain HTTP/1.1, it can't use HTTP/2. It can deal with out-of-order responses, as long as `job_id` in answer is provided. Yes, that is violation of HTTP/1.1, but as long as both sides can cope with it - it's ok.

Comment: You aren't going to get the bahavior you want with actix, it will follow the HTTP spec because that's what it's expected to do.